# How to detect the swiping of the last or first cell in UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with one row and I want to hide it if the user is trying to swipe right on the first cell or trying to swipe left on the last cell.

Just adding a left\right swipe gesture won't do the trick.
I have mannaged to do it with swipe up gesture by adding it to the first and last cell (in cellForItemAtIndexPath method).

Any Ideas?

Comment: you can get swipe direction in scrollDidScroll methos

Comment: ok, I used scrollViewDidEndDragging method. But how do I know the direction of the scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to get to the solution with the combination of @Tejas answer and comments:

```
var lastContentOffset = CGFloat()
var scrollDir = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        self.scrollDir = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    }
    else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        self.scrollDir = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)
{
    if let indexPath = self.upperCollectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems()[0]
    {
        if indexPath.item == 0 && self.scrollDir == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        {
           //hide the collection view
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For get Scroll direction

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat lastContentOffset;
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        NSLog(@"Scrolling left");
    }
    else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {
        NSLog(@"Scrolling right");
    }

    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
}
```

Comment: collectionview is ultimately sub class of UIScrollView

Comment: if you specify your problem more ,so i can suggest more specifically

Comment: I am using a collection view with one row that displays one cell at time, and it is paging enabled.
I want to hide the collectionView if the user swipe right on the first cell.

Comment: so you can use willDisplayCellForIndexPath and check if index path is not 0 then hide collection view. its easiest way

Comment: Thanks allot! I have managed to get the solution with the combination of your answer and comment, it was very helpful :-)